# Slow Query time due to additional Where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that will display almost 6000 rows instantly...but when I add a part to where condition...it slows it down incredibly...Is this to be expected? To me it would seem if anything it should speed it up since it is returning fewer rows.

Here is the basic query structure:

```
SELECT table1.itemcode, 
       table1.itemdiscount, 
       table2.categoryname, 
       table2.categorycount 
FROM   table2 
       JOIN table1 
         ON table2.categoryid = table1.categoryid 
WHERE  table1.categoryid = '125' 
       AND table2.categoryname IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
```

When I leave out the last part of the where condition, it's instantaneous almost...but add it...and out the window it goes. Am I just missing something? Or does the performance change make sense?

Comment: @AndrewBarber sorry didn't see you editing

Comment: @user3154759 We need to at least see the table structure (the data types, indexes, specifically) and an execution plan if possible.

Comment: What indexes (or indices) do you have on the tables? If you run the query in SSMS and show the actual execution plan it will give you suggestions of indexes to add to speed it up.

Comment: You might need an index on `table2.categoryname`.

Comment: Which columns in  those tables are indexed? Check your execution plan to see if the additional condition changes a seek to a scan, or something similar.

Comment: @Kermit np; your edit was much better!

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am still looking at it, just looked at the execution plan...for some reason the Inner join goes from 28% on the queries that work, to 98% when the other condition is added to the where clause!

Comment: Well it goes from a Hash match to a merge join I guess...I need to look into those more and see what exactly the deal is. Thank you all though!

Comment: Did you try my answer?  Does it have the same query plan?  You can add a join hint.

Answer (score 0):

The query optimizer may be going stupid
Try this

```
SELECT table1.itemcode, 
       table1.itemdiscount, 
       table2.categoryname, 
       table2.categorycount 
  FROM table2 
  JOIN table1 
    ON table2.categoryid = table1.categoryid 
   AND table1.categoryid = '125' 
   AND table2.categoryname IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
```

Next step is an index on table2.categoryname